# Bash number sequence returned in scientific notation?

Tags: bash, shell, integer, largenumber

I'm trying to create a file with all the numbers up 75 million on every line.

I'm typing in my terminal using Bash:

```
seq 1 75000000 > myfile.csv
```

But anything above 1 million gets turned into scientific notation and I'd want everything as integer (i.e. 7.31896e+07)

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You have an environment setting somewhere. I can do `seq 74999995 75000000` and it is all still integer values. I don't know what offhand, other than `LOCALE` would control the default here.

Comment: Please run `type seq` and report the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`seq` can take a printf-style format string to control its output. `f` format with a "precision" of 0 (i.e. nothing after the decimal point, which leaves off the decimal point itself) should do what you want:

```
$ seq 74999998 75000000
7.5e+07
7.5e+07
7.5e+07
$ seq -f %1.0f  74999998 75000000
74999998
74999999
75000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Observe that this produces integers:

```
$ seq  74999998 75000000
74999998
74999999
75000000
```

While this produces floating point numbers:

```
$ seq -f '%.5g' 74999998 75000000
7.5e+07
7.5e+07
7.5e+07
```

The output format of `seq` is controlled by the `-f` options.

How is the `-f` option being applied in your case?  One possibility is that your shell has an alias defined for `seq` that applies this option.  For example:

```
$ alias seq="seq -f '%.5g'"
$ seq 74999998 75000000
7.5e+07
7.5e+07
7.5e+07
```

You can determine if this is the case by running bash's builtin `type` command:

```
$ type seq
seq is aliased to `seq -f '%.5g''
```

#### Documentation

From `man seq`:

> ```
>    -f, --format=FORMAT
>           use printf style floating-point FORMAT
> ```

Comment: That's interesting - no alias in my case though `type seq` yields `seq is hashed (/usr/bin/seq)` so still unclear why I had that scientific formatting by default